# inherit constructor from template-dependent base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

How can I inherit the constructor of a base class, if its name depend on a template parameter (of the derived class)?

Example:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
};

struct B {
};

template <bool Abase>
struct C : public std::conditional_t<Abase, A, B> {
    using std::conditional_t<Abase, A, B>::(std::conditional_t<Abase, A, B>); // Error!
}

int main()
{
    C<true> c;
    C<false> c2;
}
```

In the program `struct C` should inherit `A::A` or `B::B`, depending on the value of the template parameter `bool Abase`.
The program, as it is written, does not compile.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: `using std::conditional_t<Abase, A, B>::conditional_t;` works (and is [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#1.sentence-3)), though it's pretty weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a type alias firstly.

```
template <bool Abase>
struct C : public std::conditional_t<Abase, A, B> {
    using base = std::conditional_t<Abase, A, B>;
    using base::base;
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n39Rv9CnSF6apy9B)